# Source for Ancient Prohibition against Writing Prayers?

Tags: tefilla, history, midrash, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer

This short article on the [History of the Siddur](https://bje.org.au/knowledge-centre/jewish-texts/siddur/history/) claims:

> In ancient times, customary daily prayers were recited by heart, or a
> reader prayed aloud and the congregation responded to the blessings
> with “Amen”. There were no books containing the texts of the prayers.
> It was said, “The writers of blessings are like those who burn the
> Torah.” (Tosef. To Shab. 13:4). Writing down the text of blessings was
> considered forbidden.

Is this true? How do I find this quote in Sefaria?

Comment: i think you need to provide more context for this question.

Comment: @David There are four claims made here. Are you asking about all of them or one in particular?

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like the reference has a typo. It should say [Tosefta Shabbat 14:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosefta_Shabbat.14.3?lang=bi):

> כותבי ברכות כשורפי תורה
>
> Those who write down blessings [i.e. prayers] are like those who burn the Torah.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud describes what you wrote:

> Whoever has not seen the Double Colonnade of Alexandria in Egypt has not seen the glory of Israel. It was like a huge basilica that contained twice the number of men who went out from Egypt, and there were 71 golden armchairs for 71 Sages, and each chair was no less than 21 talents of gold.
> And a wooden pulpit was in the middle of the palace where the attendant of the congregation stood with a scarf in his hand, and when the time came in the prayer to respond "Amen," he raised the flag, [so those who couldn’t hear because of the great crowd could know when to respond] and the whole people said "Amen."
> And they did not sit mixed; rather the goldsmiths, silversmiths, blacksmiths, coppersmiths and weavers all sat separately. And when a poor man went in, he recognized his fellow-tradesmen and went to them, and received work to support himself and his family. [Sukkah 51b]